# how to pause Kafka Consumer when I am using @KafkaListener Annotation

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am pulling data from a data base to check if I have the available system resources to process further messages coming from KafkaListener. If I my condition is not met then I want @KafkaListener to pause and when the condition is met, I want @KafkaListener to resume. How do I achieve this in spring Kafka?

Also are there any disadvantages of pausing a consumer for a particular partition?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1):

There is no `pause/resume` control in the current version. Only automatic by the Framework, when it detects slow listener.

In the latest `2.0` we have opposite situation: we don't provide automatic `pause/resume` - no reason any more, but at the same time allow to configure `@KafkaListener` method with the `Consumer` argument, so you can perform any desired logic there already.

Comment: Could you please give an example on how  to configure @KafkaListener method with the Consumer argument

Comment: One more time `AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener` is available only since version `2.0`. The listener configuration though is straightforward: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/EnableKafkaIntegrationTests.java#L1085

Comment: @ArtemBilan - Can I call Consumer.pause() safelly in 2.0 from the Message Listener or could I have concurrency problems?
Currently I face the same problem of this question: When I receive a message I have to check if I have resources to process it. If I don't, I have to wait. So I want to stop consumming messages from kafka until I am ready again.

Comment: I don't think so. As far as you pause the consumer, no any activities happen so no any concurrency problems

Comment: @Artem: Can you please post a code snippet of how to access Consumer object and then pause/resume it whenever needed?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/EnableKafkaIntegrationTests.java#L1039. But still bear in mind this is available only since the latest `2.0` version - GA in the end of this week, just after SF 5.0 GA!